# How could I connect an LED to a USB Type C connector?

Tags: led, usb, connector, connect

I’m trying to connect an LED to a USB connector, so when the cable connected, the LED lights up. I was planning to do this on a USB type C cable. How could I do this without ruining the cable functionality?

Comment: Just use the 5V on the connector. (Or buy a cable with an included LED...)

Comment: @Mike You don't know if 5V is flowing though the cable. There could be up to 48V on the cable, you need a regulator that can handle that as a resistor + a led doesn't have the range required

Comment: @Ferrybig unless you connect it to something not compliant to the USB specs, there is absolutely no reason there would be 48V on the cable. USB is 5V, and *only* if both the host and the device agree (through a negotiation scheme you can't implement with just a LED), voltage then may rise up to 48V.

Comment: @dim USB C supports power delivery, which is an USB defined protocol that runs over USB C to C cables. This is an USB protocl, so it is USB compliant. The latst revision of this protocol allows voltages up to 48V if the sink, cable and source advertise they can handle it. High voltages like 48V are typically requested hy high end laptops, while power banks and phones typically request lower voltages like 12V.

Comment: @Ferrbybig. Sorry, I didn't read the full question and was missing the "without ruining the cable functionality" part.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers. The voltage should be 5 volts since it’s purpose is to connect to a pc usb.